# Assertion error in dbus-c++ , terminates process

Tags: c++, linux, dbus

I am using the dbus-c++ binding to create a proxy for connman's Service API which is exposed on dbus.
The method found in connman's Service interface xml, looks like so:

```
<method name="GetProperties">
<arg type="a{sv}" direction="out"/>
</method>
```

The proxy file that was auto-generated using "dbusxx-xml2cpp" utility,
created the method in question like so:

```
Line 1:    std::map< std::string, ::DBus::Variant > GetProperties()
Line 2:    {
Line 3:        ::DBus::CallMessage call;
Line 4:        call.member("GetProperties");
Line 5:        ::DBus::Message ret = invoke_method (call);
Line 6:        ::DBus::MessageIter ri = ret.reader();
Line 7:        std::map< std::string, ::DBus::Variant > argout;
Line 8:        ri >> argout;
Line 9:        return argout;
Line 10:    }
```

It's on Line 8, that I get the warning/error, 
on x86 running Ubuntu 11.04 with libdbus-c++-1-0 package(0~20110310-1ubuntu1):

```
process 30342: arguments to dbus_message_iter_open_container() were incorrect, assertion "(type == DBUS_TYPE_STRUCT && contained_signature == NULL) || (type == DBUS_TYPE_DICT_ENTRY && contained_signature == NULL) || (type == DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT && contained_signature != NULL) || (type == DBUS_TYPE_ARRAY && contained_signature != NULL)" failed in file dbus-message.c line 2677.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 30342: dbus message iterator looks uninitialized or corrupted
```

....and lots more..... But the process **DOES NOT terminate**/abort here.

On meego however, running on an arm based target,
the **process TERMINATES** after this assertion error!

The package used in meego on the arm based board is:
    libdbus-c++-0.5.1-4.3.armv7hl.rpm
    libdbus-c++-devel-0.5.1-4.3.armv7hl.rpm

Please help in resolving this issue.
Is there another way in which the iterator can insert the DICT value - (std::map< std::string, ::DBus::Variant > ) without throwing these assertion errors?

Any help would be appreciated.

-Roy Samuel.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug in the dbus-c++ library. More information can be found here:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3151818&group_id=236997&atid=1101682

I suggest you to either:

- modify the sourcecode of dbus-c++ (change one line in message.cpp)
- use the async version of sjames ( here https://gitorious.org/~sjames/dbus-cplusplus/async )

Regards,

Bigfoot.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I just fixed the bug to respect spec of this [method](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusMessage.html#ga943150f4e87fd8507da224d22c266100)